# Updating Collection from other collection for matching items

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I have two collections as mentioned below. I have update two properties of "trade" from the other collection "refData" if those values exists in "refData".

**Model:**

```
class Trade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PayIndex { get; set; }
    public string RecIndex { get; set; }
    public string PayCurrency { get; set; }
    public string RecCurrency { get; set; }
}
class RefData
{
    public string IndexLabel { get; set; }
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
}
```

**Sample Date:**

```
var refData = new List<RefData>
        {
            new RefData { IndexLabel = "A1", Symbol="ABC1"},
            new RefData { IndexLabel = "A2", Symbol="ABC2"},
            new RefData { IndexLabel = "B1", Symbol="BCD1"},
            new RefData { IndexLabel = "B2", Symbol="BCD2"},
        };
        var trades = new List<Trade>
        {
            new Trade { Id = 1, PayIndex = "A1", RecIndex = "B1"},
            new Trade { Id = 2, PayIndex = "A2", RecIndex = ""},
            new Trade { Id = 3, PayIndex = "", RecIndex = "B2"},
            new Trade { Id = 4, PayIndex = "A3", RecIndex = "B3"}
        };
```

I want to update PayCurrency and RecCurrency of "trades" with Symbol property of "refData" if trade's PayIndex and RecCurrency exists in "refData".

**Output:**

```
var Output = new List<Trade>
        {
            new Trade { Id = 1, PayIndex = "A1", RecIndex = "B1", PayCurrency = "ABC1", RecCurrency="BCD1"},
            new Trade { Id = 2, PayIndex = "A2", RecIndex = "", PayCurrency = "ABC2", RecCurrency=""},
            new Trade { Id = 3, PayIndex = "", RecIndex = "B2", PayCurrency = "", RecCurrency="BCD2"},
            new Trade { Id = 4, PayIndex = "A3", RecIndex = "B3", PayCurrency = "", RecCurrency=""}
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For c#6 and above you can do like below

```
  var result = trades.Select(t => new Trade() {
       Id= t.Id,
       PayIndex = t.PayIndex,
       RecIndex = t.RecIndex,
       PayCurrency = refData.SingleOrDefault(r => r.IndexLabel.ToLower().Equals(t.PayIndex.ToLower()))?.Symbol ?? "",
       RecCurrency = refData.SingleOrDefault(r => r.IndexLabel.ToLower().Equals(t.RecIndex.ToLower()))?.Symbol ?? ""

    }).ToList();
```

For Older versions

```
  var result = trades.Select(t => new Trade() {
       Id= t.Id,
       PayIndex = t.PayIndex,
       RecIndex = t.RecIndex,
       PayCurrency = refData.SingleOrDefault(r => r.IndexLabel.ToLower().Equals(t.PayIndex.ToLower())) != null ?  refData.SingleOrDefault(r => r.IndexLabel.ToLower().Equals(t.PayIndex.ToLower())).Symbol : "",
       RecCurrency = refData.SingleOrDefault(r => r.IndexLabel.ToLower().Equals(t.RecIndex.ToLower())) != null ? refData.SingleOrDefault(r => r.IndexLabel.ToLower().Equals(t.RecIndex.ToLower())).Symbol : ""

    }).ToList();
```

[Here is working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3Cxu8m)

Update using @SAJ answer

```
 var output = (from r in trades
                      join p in refData on r.PayIndex equals p.IndexLabel
                      into g1
                      from s in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join t in refData on r.RecIndex equals t.IndexLabel into g2
                      from a in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select Trade { Id=r.Id,PayIndex=r.PayIndex,RecIndex=r.RecIndex, RecCurrency = a != null ? a.Symbol : "", PayCurrency = s != null ? s.Symbol : ""}).ToList();
```

Comment: Glad it helped i updated the answer using join see if that works faster

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    var output = (from r in trades
                      join p in refData on r.PayIndex equals p.IndexLabel
                      into g1
                      from s in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join t in refData on r.RecIndex equals t.IndexLabel into g2
                      from a in g2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new { r, RecSymbol = a?.Symbol, PaySymbol = s?.Symbol }).ToList();

        output.ForEach(o =>
        {
            o.r.PayCurrency = o.PaySymbol;
            o.r.RecCurrency = o.RecSymbol;
        });
```